# Cannot connect to local node using polkadot/api library. Return error unexpected character '#' in the library

Tags: polkadot-js

I'm trying to connect to local node using polkadot/api library but when I start my project it return this error in the library
[image]

Here is my code:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means you need to use a babel loader that supports [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).

We also ran into this issue, and fixed it with proper build config. We have a working build [here](https://github.com/LibertyDSNP/example-client-frequency) but we're using TypeScript not JavaScript.  Maybe that might help you.

It also looks like you aren't the only one, someone reported [something like it](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4500) earlier this year.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your client saves my days!!!

Comment: Great! If you don't mind, would you please mark your question as answered so people can easily find what worked?  Thanks :)